# How to populate list and piece them together in POJO class

Tags: java, json, arraylist, pojo

I have this JSON which I transformed into a POJO consisting of 3 different classes.

```
{
    "Id": "2a0dd1fc",
    "name": "AABBCCDD",
    "description": "test",
    "active": true,
    "Groups": [
      {
        "agentGroups": [
          {
            "Id": "AXSNqSWSILMPnVvB-Cdc"
          }
        ],
        "order": 1,
        "duration": 0
      },
      {
        "agentGroups": [
          {
            "Id": "AXZlGzTR4pYEiRgUOqOL"
          }
        ],
        "order": 2,
        "duration": 60
      }
    ]
  }
```

-----------------------------------AgentGroup.java-----------------------------------

```
public class AgentGroup{

       public String id;
//Getter & Setters
}
```

-----------------------------------Group.java-----------------------------------

```
public class Group{
   ** public List<AgentGroup> agentGroups;**
    public int order;
    public int duration;
//Getter & Setters
public void setAgentGroups(List<AgentGroup> agentGroups) {
this.agentGroups = agentGroups;
}
}
```

-----------------------------------DistributionGroup.java-----------------------------------

```
public class DistributionGroup{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public boolean active;
    **public List<Group> groups;**
//Getter & Setters
public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
this.groups = groups;
}
}
```

As you can see Group is a List and agentGroup is also a List.
I'm having difficulty populating/setting up the list values and piece them together and return the Group as a list.

I have tried to set it up like this but it does not seem to be working:
//function call

```
List<Group> groups=createDistributionGroup(teamIds,1)
```

Function:

```
public static Group createDistributionGroup(List<String> teamIds, int order) {
        Group grp= new Group();
        grp.setOrder(order);
        grp.setDuration(60);

        //Now How do I put AgentGroup in a list and return the group.       
        
        
        return grp;
        
    }
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model represents your json, more or less.  Here's a simple test that you can use to validate it.

```
String s = "{\n"
    + "    \"id\": \"2a0dd1fc\",\n"
    + "    \"name\": \"AABBCCDD\",\n"
    + "    \"description\": \"test\",\n"
    + "    \"active\": true,\n"
    + "    \"groups\": [\n"
    + "      {\n"
    + "        \"agentGroups\": [\n"
    + "          {\n"
    + "            \"id\": \"AXSNqSWSILMPnVvB-Cdc\"\n"
    + "          }\n"
    + "        ],\n"
    + "        \"order\": 1,\n"
    + "        \"duration\": 0\n"
    + "      },\n"
    + "      {\n"
    + "        \"agentGroups\": [\n"
    + "          {\n"
    + "            \"id\": \"AXZlGzTR4pYEiRgUOqOL\"\n"
    + "          }\n"
    + "        ],\n"
    + "        \"order\": 2,\n"
    + "        \"duration\": 60\n"
    + "      }\n"
    + "    ]\n"
    + "  }";

DistributionGroup distributionGroup = new ObjectMapper().reader()
    .readValue(s, DistributionGroup.class);
```

I did make a few changes to your json, I set the field `Id` to `id`, and `Groups` to `groups`, notice the case difference.  If you cannot change the json, then you have to add an annotation to your model attributes to let them know that they don't conform to the bean spec.  For instance, if you wish to preserve `Id` in your json, then add `@JsonAlias("Id")` to the id property on your class, so the field would look like

```
@JsonAlias("Id")
public String id;
```

To add AgentGroups to your Group in the `createDistributionGroup` method, it would look something like this:

```
AgentGroup ag1 = new AgentGroup();
ag1.setId("10");

AgentGroup ag2 = new AgentGroup();
ag1.setId("20");

grp.setAgentGroups(Arrays.asList(ag1, ag2));
```